# Diagnosing Microsoft Edge Chromium memory usage

Tags: memory, microsoft-edge

On my girlfriends laptop with 8 GB of memory the system seems to start to swap (use pagefile) when she has a handful of browser tabs open. I personally use Firefox on Linux and don't seem to have these problems. Is there something that we can do to still have tons of open tabs but not use so much memory? I guess it would be fine if the content of tabs had to be reloaded upon activation.

Comment: Tabs require memory.

Comment: Yes, but like 800 MB per Tab?

Comment: You're still just assuming it's just Edge. If you've checked the Taskmanager adding that info here would go a long way toward making your question better. We only know what you tell us. You're our eyes and ears.